# how to provide secret_key to appspot

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app that uses sessions and on my box I entered a secret_key to make it work. when i uploaded to appspot it crashes because the secret_key is not set. how do I get around this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~canada-math/1.387800730829010736/login.py", line 30, in dispatch
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2_extras/sessions.py", line 454, in get_store
    store = request.registry[key] = factory(request)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2_extras/sessions.py", line 308, in __init__
    required_keys=('secret_key',))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1361, in load_config
    self._validate_required(key, config, required_keys)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1375, in _validate_required
    'Missing configuration keys for %r: %r.' % (key, missing))
Exception: Missing configuration keys for 'webapp2_extras.sessions': ['secret_key'].
```

Comment: You should set secret_key for production environment.

Answer (score 0):

From https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html#webapp2_extras.sessions.SessionStore

> A configuration dict can be passed to `__init__()`, or the application
>   must be initialized with the secret_key configuration defined. The
>   configuration is a simple dictionary:
>
> ```
> config = {}
> config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {
>     'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key',
> }
>
> app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
>     ('/', HomeHandler),
> ], config=config)
> ```

You would need to use your own value for `my-super-secret-key` and you should define this in your main wsgi app.